# Newtonsoft serialization vs ASP.NET serialization

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

If I have a simple class:

```
public class UserId
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and I pass it to HttpRequest.CreateResponse() the output is:

```
{ "id": "1234bcf6678" }
```

However, if I use a JsonSerializer I get:

```
"{ \"id\": \"1234bcf6678\" }"
```

I understand that the second one is effectively a json string but how can I use the JsonSerializer AND pass the result from it to HttpRequest.CreateResponse() in such a fashion as to get the first output (i.e. no escaped quotes)?

I know there is a related question on SO but I want to use the Newtonsoft serializer because it allows me to correctly handle serialize some generic lists and derived objects.

For extra context its probably worth knowing that I'm doing this inside Azure Functions. I see that Web API has `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration` available but not sure functions do.

Comment: ASP.Net uses Json.net internally, and you can configure it in the application startup. Can you be more specific about the situation you have where ASP.Net is not returning the right output?

Comment: I just made an edit. This is inside Azure Functions so I'm not sure I have the same override possibilities through GlobalConfiguration as in Web API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the JsonSerializer, and return the resulting string, it's being serialized as Json *again*. You'll have to bypass the `HttpRequest.CreateResponse()` extension method, and create the response manually - that way, you can set the content and the content type yourself. A helpful starting point would be to look at the [source code for `CreateResponse`](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs) (It's around line 332). Instead of using `ObjectContent<T>`, you would use `StringContent`, with a media type of 'application/json'.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it sounds a reasonable approach. It is end of my day here so I'll try later and mark as answered if I get what I need then.

Comment: Couldn't relax without giving it a go. Solution is:
    var response = new HttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(<output from newtonsoft>);
    return response;

Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Just a heads up, you might want to set the media type explicitly to 'application/json' - I'm pretty sure StringContent deafults to 'application/text'. This will help, for example, when you are consuming the output using jQuery, as it will automatically parse the json and return an object, rather than a string.

Comment: Hey Andrew, is there a difference between text/json and application/json? I've never seen it referenced as application/json

Comment: The W3 consortium does list `application/json` as being the official MIME type for json data. Other than that, there's no real difference - pretty much every consuming application will accept either one.